# Explain this to me please

Tags: c#

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Append(daysOfWeek[i]);
    if (i < daysOfWeek.Length - 2)
        sb.Append(", ");
    else if (i == daysOfWeek.Length - 2)
        sb.Append(" and ");
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

I understand everything in this chunk of code except for what the -2 does after the `daysOfWeek.Length`

What is it subtracting 2 from?

Comment: It's subtracting 2 from the days of the week. Probably intended to stick the word "and" on there for the last day of the week. Why don't you try it with and without that and see what the difference in output is? The code is front of you to play with.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about writing good titles, and the section headed "Search, and research".

Comment: daysOfWeek is an object which has a property (probably int) that you can think of as "7". Then subtract 2 from it, to give 5.

Comment: the same as `i  <  (daysOfWeek.Length - 2)`

Comment: Arrays start on index 0, so an array of 1 elements only have the index 0,, one of two have 0,1 and so on. He is getting the count of items in the array, if the loop is the penultimate (array.Length - 2) one he adds " and " to concatenate the names, if it's previous adds a comma, else adds nothing as there will be no next item

Comment: Basically `daysOfWeek.Length - 2` is the index of the next to last item.  So before the next to last item you put ", " after each item then for the next to last you put " and " after the item and the last doesn't get anything put after it.

Comment: Come on, should this not be in another exchange channel?!? Rep scroungers are out.

Answer (score 1):

Well `daysOfWeek.Length` is however many days are in the array `daysOfWeek` which should be Sun Mon Tue Wed etc if I had to guess.  The -2 subtracts from that number, which then compares to which iteration the `i` is on.  I'm not too familiar with C# but if the array has all 7 days of the week, it should be `7 - 2`.  Since `0` is the first place in an array, this means that it should print something like, `Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday`

Comment: Only one "and" (not two).

Comment: it's 7 - 2, length is the item count, not the index, to get the index you do Length - 1, and as this is for the penultimate element he uses 7-2;

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    var daysOfWeek = GetDaysOfWeek();
    MethodA(daysOfWeek);
    MethodB(daysOfWeek);
}

void MethodA(string[] daysOfWeek)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(daysOfWeek[i]);

        if (i < daysOfWeek.Length - 2)
            sb.Append(", ");
        else if (i == daysOfWeek.Length - 2)
            sb.Append(" and ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}

void MethodB(string[] daysOfWeek)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(daysOfWeek[i]);

        if (i < daysOfWeek.Length)
            sb.Append(", ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}

public string[] GetDaysOfWeek()
{
    return (new List<string>{"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"}).ToArray() ;
}
```

It's for beautification. It sticks " and " into the string builder before the last day of the week.

> Method A: Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday and Saturday
>
> Method B: Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday,

Next time you have a question about simple code like this, try it! See what it does. Create a small program like the one I created above and run it in Visual Studio or [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Answer (score 0):

`int i` is the index of used to iterate over `daysOfWeek`

In C#, arrays are zero based, that means that the first element of an array is `MyArray[0]`

`MyArray.Length` returns the number of elements in the array, starting from one.

If your array only has 1 element, the `.Length` is 1; you can't do `MyArray[MyArray.Length]` because that would cause an exception; You do `MyArray[MyArray.Length - 1]` so you "zero base" your Lenght.

This is your loop with comments:

```
for (int i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Append(daysOfWeek[i]);
    if (i < daysOfWeek.Length - 2) //If the element is not the last or the penultimate do something
        sb.Append(", ");
    else if (i == daysOfWeek.Length - 2) //if the element is the penultimate of my array, instead of a "comma", put an "and".
        sb.Append(" and ");
}
```